# How does inheritance & abstraction work with multiple classes? [java]

Tags: java, inheritance, abstract-class, multiple-inheritance

I'm having a problem understanding how inheritance works in Java. I have 3 classes that extend each other. The third class is the tricky one which I am having a problem with.

```
public abstract class Shape{ 
    //methods and variables
    protected final static int X_MAX_SIZE = 800;
    protected final static int Y_MAX_SIZE = 600;
    private int xCord;
    private int yCord;

    public void setX(int newX){
        if(newX > 0 && newX < 800){
            this.xCord = newX;
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("Invalid size.");
            this.xCord = 0;
        }
    }

    public int getX(){
        return xCord;
    }

    public void setY(int newY){
        if(newY > 0 && newY < 600){
          this.yCord = newY;  
        }
        else{
            System.out.println("Invalid size.");
            this.yCord = 0;
        }

    }

    public int getY(){
        return yCord;
    }

    public Shape(){

    }

    public Shape(int xCord, int yCord){

    }

    abstract void display();
    abstract double area();

}

public class Rectangle extends Shape {
     // the inherited methods and calculations
    int width, height;

    public int getHeight(){
        return height;
    }    
    public void setHeight(int newHeight){
        this.height = newHeight;
    }

    public int getWidth(){
        return width;
    }
    public void setWidth(int newWidth){
        this.width = newWidth;
    }

    public Rectangle(){

    }

    public Rectangle(int x, int y, int height, int width){
        setX(x);
        setY(y);
        setHeight(height);
        setWidth(width);

    }

    @Override
    void display(){
        String toScreen = "Rectangle X: " + getX() + "\nRectangle Y: " + getY();
        String toScreenInfo = "\nRectangle height: " + getHeight() + "\nRectangle Width:getWidth();
        String toScreenArea = "\nRectangle area: " + area();
        System.out.println(toScreen + toScreenInfo + toScreenArea);
    }

    @Override
    double area(){
        return (width * height);
    }

    }

}

public class Square extends Rectangle {
    // more methods, but no new variables. & calculations


    public Square(int x, int y, int  height, int width){
        setX(x);
        setY(y);
        setHeight(height);
        setWidth(width);
    }

    public Square(){
        super();        
    }

    @Override
    public void setHeight(int height){
        if(height != getWidth()){
            height = getWidth();
        }
    } 
    @Override
    public void setWidth(int width){
        if(width != getHeight()){
            width = getHeight();
        }
    }  

    @Override
    double area(){
        return (width * height);
    }

    @Override
    void display(){
        String toScreen = "Square area is " + area();
    }
    }
}
```

the class Square I am having trouble even calling in main. 
So my goal here it change the values from Square class to make sure 'height' and 'width' are equal to each other in order to make a square. The constraint being I can't create any new variables in the get/set and constructor.

Comment: Ummm, do you think we are mind readers?  There is not **nearly** enough informmation for anybody to help you.

Comment: Is this all the code? Or is there more code that you are working with that might contribute to the problem you are having? And, what exactly is the problem, again?

Comment: You need to post an example which actually produces the results you claim to receive.

Comment: Yes I have more code, I'll edit now

Comment: Better.  But you say you're having trouble calling the `Square` class from `main`, but you don't show us the `main` code where you're having the problem.  Please include that, and include the error message the compiler is generating, or an exception backtrace, or details of whatever other error you're encountering.

Comment: @ajb I actually got the call to main right. I didn't system.out.println()... :[

Comment: @ajb but the values are 0.0 for Square

Comment: Because default values for height and width are zero (being int). When you call setHeight(50), width is zero at this point so (height != getWidth()) passes and height = getWidth() = 0. Same happens for setWidth(). Because of this dependency values will never be set.

Answer (score 0):

Inheritance should always express an "is a" relationship between objects, as is true in your example.

A square is a rectangle.
A rectangle is a shape.

If objects do not naturally have an "is a" relationship, then inheritance is probably a bad way to organize them (an interface-based type hierarchy may be better).

A square will have the members (methods and fields) of a rectangle.
A rectangle will have the members (methods and fields) of a shape.  A subclass may override a parent method to provide more specific behavior.

If you're having a more particular problem, you'll have to give us more to work with.

Comment: A square is a rectangle *in math*. A square is *not* a rectangle when programming. This is a classic example used to illustrate the Liskov Substitution Principle.

Comment: A square _is_ a rectangle when programming, if there are no setter methods that can change the height or width independently.

Comment: @EricStein: A square may or may not be a rectangle in programming.  It depends on the precise semantics of square and rectangle in the abstraction being modeled.  For the purposes of an introduction to inheritance, I intended a simple illustration of an "is a" relationship.  This was not inappropriate.

Comment: @scottb In the abstraction he is modeling, clearly a Square is not a Rectangle.

Comment: @ajb No, even changing the height and width together is a problem. The issue is mutability. If a method takes a Rectangle and calls setSize(50, 200), the result if the Rectangle was a Square is unclear and probably wrong. You could, in theory, make Square extend Rectangle if they were both immutable. I would argue that's asking for trouble, but it's valid.

Comment: @EricStein `setSize(50,200)` would still be changing the height and width independently, in the way I intended the term, even though it's by the same method call.  However, suppose the only method that mutates the `Rectangle` is `scale(double factor)` which multiplies both the height and width by the same factor.  Now there is no LSP problem.  That's what I was thinking, but I see that my use of the term "independently" was ambiguous.

Answer (score 0):

if you have any abstract methods in class shape override each and every of it in the Square class or in Rectangle class.
If you would like to create object of Rectangle too then you should override all abstract methods in Rectangle only.

and the inheritance here is multilevel not multiple

Answer (score 0):

What you want can't be done. This is, in fact, the classic example used to demonstrate the Liskov Substitution Principle. Square cannot extend Rectangle, and Rectangle cannot extend Square. To wit:

```
class Square extends Rectangle {
    ...
}

public void someMethod(final Rectangle r) {
    r.setHeight(300);
    r.setWidth(500);
}

final Square square = new Square(200, 200);
someMethod(square);
display(square);  // UHOH!!
```

Comment: Well, `Square` could extend `Rectangle` if they were immutable.  Or possibly in some other restricted conditions.  Anyway, of course this *can* be done, even if it shouldn't, but I think instructors are still using examples like this to teach the mechanics of inheritance.  So if someone is at that level and trying to figure out the basics, throwing LSP at them is perhaps not the most helpful answer.

Comment: @ajb - I think the loss will be minimum if basics are made clear as soon as possible.Just my point of view.

Comment: @ajb I was kinda hoping the instructor was trying to point out LSP as a pitfall of concrete extension. Regardless of the instructor's intent, there's no good way to do what the OP wants to accomplish.

Answer (score -2):

The problem is that in `Rectangle`, you have methods `setHeight` and `setWidth`, which set the instance variables `height` and `width`.  In `Square`, you don't declare new instance variables.  So in order to set the height and width, you'll need to use the `setHeight` and `setWidth` methods declared in `Rectangle`.

However, you don't do this for a `Square`.  The `Square` class overrides the `setHeight` and `setWidth` methods.  For those to set the instance variables, they will need to call the `setHeight` and `setWidth` methods defined in `Rectangle`.  The way to do this is:

```
super.setHeight(h);   // calls the Rectangle method, which sets the variable
super.setWidth(w);
```

Since you don't use this, the `setHeight` and `setWidth` methods in `Square` just call each other, not the ones in `Rectangle`, and the result is that the `height` and `width` variables never get set.

Comment: Could someone explain the downvote?  Did I get something incorrect?  Or is someone just upset that I didn't get on the "you can't do this" LSP bandwagon?  In any case, the questioner needs to learn about the `super.method` syntax.

Comment: Based on this, does this mean that any time an instructor assigns a recursion assignment that isn't really appropriate for recursion (like most of them), should we downvote everyone who tries to help the student?